# <ltng:require> not firing afterScriptsLoaded with Pdf.js

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pdf

I tried downloading the Prebuilt (ES5-compatible) Stable version of pdf.js from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download and added it to Static Resources.

But it doesn't fire afterScriptsLoaded. Any help here!

**Component**

```
<aura:component
    implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
    access="global">

    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Pdf + '/build/pdf.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({

  init: function (component, event, helper) {
    console.log("Init");
  }
})
```

Comment: have you used the browser tools to see if there are any errors coming from the load of the static resource, or this component?

Comment: No errors in the browser console.